# Why can't I access this field? (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I really can't figure out why I can't access the user_id field for the class Post. I have it as a field in my database (I can see it, and it isn't blank. Yet for some reason, I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `user_id' for #<Class:0x103497448>
Extracted source (around line #10):

7:   <h2>Topics</h2>
8:   <% @board.topics.each do |topic| %>
9:     <% @post = topic.posts(1) %>
10:     <b><%= User.find(@post.user_id).username %> says <%= link_to topic.subject,      [@board, topic] %></b><br />
11:   <% end %>
12: <% end %>
13:
```

Comment: What do you intend by this `@post = topic.posts(1)`?

Comment: That's the first post for that topic. A topic has_many posts -- I want to get the first post for each topic and then get the user who made that post

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the correct post in your @post variable?

Comment: I guess I'm not -- I'm getting some random generic object. But I don't know why I should be getting that if I do topic.posts

Answer (score 0):

`topic.posts(1)` will return an array. Hence `#<Class:0x103497448>`

The right way to get the first post for a topic would be

```
9:     <% @post = topic.posts.first %>
10:     <b><%= User.find(@post.user_id).username %> says <%= link_to topic.subject,      [@board, topic] %></b><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<% @post = topic.posts.limit(1) %>`